# A Smooth Function with Peculiar Properties

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory, smooth-functions

Suppose $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ is a smooth function and define $E_f := \{x\in\mathbb R^n\;|\;f(x)=0\text{ and }\nabla f(x)\ne 0\}$. Can we find $f$ such that $E_f$ has positive $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Use the implicit function theorem to show that locally, $E_f$ has measure zero.

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot!

Comment: @copper.hat Does your comment(answer) applies also for non-analytic smooth functions like [flat functions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_function)?

Comment: @Joako It applies to any $C^1$ function. Roughly it says that locally $E_f$ is $n-1$ dimensional. The definition of $E_f$ rules out flat spots (at least open sets on which $f$ is constant).

Comment: @copper.hat but smooth bump functions like $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 1, \ x=0,\\ 0,\ |x|\geq 1,\\ \dfrac{1}{1+\exp\left(\dfrac{1-2|x|}{x^2-|x|}\right)},\ \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$ do have flat spots in open intervals, I am missing something?

Comment: I am not sure what your point is. The definition of $E_f$ requires that the point is not critical, but it could easily be 'flat' along some direction (for example, if $f$ is affine) . In your example, $E_f = \emptyset$.